# When creating a fluent api, how do they chained methods get context from previous methods?

Tags: c#, api, lambda, fluent

I'm looking at this open source project, and the fluent api looks like:

```
baseEngine.For<Foo1>()
            .Setup(f => f.Value)
              .MustEqual(1);
```

Then MustEqual method's parameter list it:

```
 public static M MustEqual<M, T, R>(this IMustPassRule<M, T, R> mpr, R value)
 {
    return mpr.MustPassRule(new EqualRule<R>(value));
 }
```

for more details: http://rulesengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9077#137411

**So what I'm trying to get at is, the call to MustEqual is being passed only a single arguement, since it is fluent, is it somehow implicitly picking up other required parameters from the previously chained calls?**

Comment: Are you talking about "this IMustPassRule<M, T, R> mpr"? If so then this is a C# construct to create an extension method for the IMustPassRule interface

Answer (score 2):

The state gets stored in the object itself by those previous methods, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

Extension Methods allow static methods to be invoked with instance method syntax. For instance,

```
something.MustEqual(1);
```

is equivalent to

```
RulesHelper.MustEqual(something, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice example can be found in LINQ

The `IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy` returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`

This second interface keeps track of the order so the `IOrderedEnumerable<T>.ThenBy` is able to do a sub-sort. To make things smooth the interface derives from `IEnumerable<T>`